# webform "Load a pre-built option list" not shown

Tags: hooks, webforms

I use the webform module to build a form. I'd like to fill a select with values coming from a database. I use the hook

Here is some sample code:

```
    /**
     * Implementation of hook_webform_select_options_info().
     * See webform/webform_hooks.php for further information on this hook in the Webform API.
     */
    function custom_webform_pre_build_list_webform_select_options_info() {
        $items = array();
        $items['user_roles'] = array(
            'title' => t('Roles'),
            'options callback' => 'custom_webform_pre_build_list_user_roles'
        );

       return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Build an options list to be used with webforms select list based in drupal roles
     */
    function custom_webform_pre_build_list_user_roles() {
        $roles = user_roles();

        $contentarray = array();

        $contentarray[0] = t("Select user role");

            #$new_taxonomies = array();
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                $contentarray[$role] = t($role);
            }

        return $contentarray;
    }
```

I activated the module. Now my problem is to select this list of entries for my select. I cannot see the "Load a pre-built option list" when I click "Add" under "options" for the select box in the form builder.
What am I doing wrong?

I'm using version 3.x of webform and the "Options element" module.

Thx, Sven

Answer (score 1):

I had the formbuilder module activated. There is no possibility to "Load a pre-built option list"! I deactivated it then it works. The problem is, there is not a nice builder ui anymore ;-(